# How are taps proven to work for LFSRs?

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, computer-science, it.information-theory, applied-mathematics

Obviously, you can exhaustively check that it lands on every state except the zero state, but for large *linear feedback shift registers* (LFSR), this quickly becomes infeasible.

Wikipedia states the following [on its LFSR page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LFSR):

- The LFSR will only be maximum-length if the number of taps is even; just 2 or 4 taps can suffice even for extremely long sequences.
- The set of taps must be relatively prime, and share no common divisor to all taps.
- There can be more than one maximum-length tap sequence for a given LFSR length
- Once one maximum-length tap sequence has been found, another automatically follows. If the tap sequence, in an n-bit LFSR, is [n, A, B, C, 0], where the 0 corresponds to the x0 = 1 term, then the corresponding 'mirror' sequence is [n, n − C, n − B, n − A, 0]. So the tap sequence [32, 7, 3, 2, 0] has as its counterpart [32, 30, 29, 25, 0]. Both give a maximum-length sequence.

I don't believe that this is a complete set of requirements for taps. Nevertheless this doesn't touch the subject of proving the taps create a maximum-length LFSR.

I know there are tables out there, but I am interested specifically in finding and proving that a set of taps create a maximum-length LFSR.

Comment: LFSRA or LFSRB ?

Comment: As the wiki page itself says, you should be looking at primitive polynomials.

Comment: I edited in *something* even though I know nothing of the field. I do know that linear-logic feels like the wrong tag (there is a field of mathematical logic called linear logic which has restrictions on the usual structural rules of sequent calculus). 

Comment: @BS, I've never heard of an LFSRB. @Todd, thanks, I just couldn't create a tag.

Answer (score 10):

This wikipedia page is not particularly well-written and the list you quote is just a list of observations, confusingly phrased. Some of them include necessary conditions for the LFSR to be maximal but not a sufficient one.

Everything is best phrased in terms of the characteristic polynomial $f=1+x^{n_1}+\cdots+x^{n_r}$, where $n_1 < \cdots <n_r $ are the taps and $n=n_r$. This polynomial is considered over the field of two elements (i.e. modulo 2). The condition on the polynomial for the LFSR to be maximal is that $f$ is (irreducible and) primitive, i.e. a root of $f$ in the field of $2^n$ elements generates its multiplicative group. Now for the four bulleted statements;

First, $r$ has to be even, for otherwise $(x+1)$ divides $f$. It is a **conjecture** that for every $n$ there is a primitive polynomial with $r=2$ or $4$.

If $k>1$ divides all the $n_i$, then $f(x)=g(x^k)$, $g$ has degree $n/k$ and a root of $g$ will have order at most $2^{n/k}-1$. Since the $k$-th power of a root of $f$ is a root of $g$, the order of a root of will be at most $k(2^{n/k}-1) < 2^n-1$.

There can be more than one primitive polynomial, in fact there are $\phi(2^n-1)/n$ of them.

Finally, if $f$ is primitive then clearly so is $x^nf(1/x)$ which gives the fourth statement.

To actually check if $f$ is primitive, computing in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(f(x))$, you need to show that $x^{(2^n-1)/d}\ne 1$ for all non-trivial factors $d$ of $2^n-1$. If you can factor $2^n-1$ this is a reasonably simple task.